# Creating an AMD module using require.js

Tags: requirejs, amd

I have the following function:

```
function(){
    add: function(x, y){
        return console.log(x + y);
    }
}
```

How do I `define()` this as an AMD (Asynchronous Module Definition) compatible module using `require.js` and then use it in the browser?

I'm looking specially for an example using `jsfiddle` to show it works in the browser directly.

Comment: You might want to check your syntax for the example code

Comment: What's wrong with the syntax?

Comment: Instead of replying that you'd rather copy paste it in jsbin.com, e.g.,  and see for yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When directly defining an AMD module in a browser, the module cannot be anonymous, it must have a name otherwise `require.js` will throw the error `Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module`.

If you are using the r.js optimizer you **can** define anonymous AMD modules and r.js will look after module names. This is designed to avoid conflicting module names.

```
// Define a module (export)
define('a', {
    add: function(x, y){
         return console.log(x + y);
     }
});

// Use the module (import)
require(['a'], function(a){
    a.add(1, 2);
});

require(['a'], function(a){
    a.add(4, 6);
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jasdeepkhalsa/NssGv/).

Answer (score 12):

If no dependencies:

**test.js:**

```
define(function(){
    return {
       add: function(x, y){
           return console.log(x + y);
       }
    };
});
```

With dependencies

```
define(['dep1', 'dep2'], function(dep1, dep2) {
    return {
       add: function(x, y){
           return console.log(x + y);
       }
    };
});
```

Here is a example with [require](http://jsfiddle.net/asgoth/tHkHw/).

To reference the module, use require:

**bootstrap.js:**

```
/*global define, require */

require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js'
});
require(['test'], function (test) {
    'use strict';

    test.add(4, 5);
});
```

My folder structure:

- root (aka public)

  - js

    - bootstrap.js
    - test.js
  - lib

    - require

      - require.js
  - index.html

In the html page (in jade, similar in html):

```
<body>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/require/require.js" data-main="js/bootstrap"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: If I try to run your first example in jsfiddle, `require.js` gives the error `Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module`?

Comment: Your code still throws an error in jsfiddle due to referencing. If you see my answer above, if you're directly defining a module on the web it cannot be anonymous, it needs to have a name :)

Comment: Very strange, since i tried it on my local webserver (not in jsFiddle however)

Comment: What does your folder/file structure look like? I couldn't get it working on my local webserver

Comment: Yes that works :) Thanks for the clarity. I think the only reason this doesn't work online is because jsfiddle doesn't store examples as a file and requirejs looks for a file structure for anonymous modules

Comment: [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/) might be easier to test this. It allows you to add files (instead of inline)